# Appending </tr> tag in a table is not reading

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have a table that I prepopulated with JSON and am trying to add collapsables in between certain rows.  I can't seem to append a closing  tag to start a new row for some reason. It keeps appending itself 
like so:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
<!--it inserts here and doesn't read the first </tr> in the variable -->
</tr>
<!--but I want to insert a new tr here-->
<tr></tr>
```

This is what I have:

```
var euheadertr = '</tr>\
      <tr class="collapsableRow">\
        <td class="regionTab" colspan="7">\
          <label for="eu">EU</label>\
          <input type="checkbox" name="eu" id="eu" data-toggle="toggle" hidden>\
        </td></tr>';

$('#secondTable tr:nth-child(3)').append(euheadertr);
```

I'm also tried :

```
$('#secondTable tbody tr:nth-child(3)').append(euheadertr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking to use [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) which adds after the element you select instead of appending it inside

```
$('#secondTable tr:nth-child(3)').after(euheadertr);
```